# Score collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

At a first collision I add 1 score, the second collision adds 2 to score, in the third collision added 3 score. Where is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
   projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstNode, monster: secondNode)
    };

        score = score + 1
        GameState.sharedInstance.score += score
        GameState.sharedInstance.saveState()
    lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use two variables for the score? Do they need to be the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep *two* variables for score, and you add 1 to `score` and `score` to the total. Unless that is what you wanted (it seems not), change the 2nd occurrence to

```
GameState.sharedInstance.score += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
GameState.sharedInstance.score += score
```

You're adding `1` to `score`, and then you're adding `score` to `GameState.sharedInstance.score`. Try changing it to

```
GameState.sharedInstance.score = score
```